# Swift 3 - Bundle.main.path with same file name in different directories

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Long story short, I have two settings files that *must* have the same name. They're currently in separate folders, something like:

```
Resources/brand/dev/settings.file
Resources/brand/prod/settings.file
```

However I can't seem to get Swift to grab the file out, it always comes up as `nil`

```
var file = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"settings", ofType:"file", inDirectory:"Resources/brand/dev")
```

If I remove one of the files, and the `inDirectory` parameter everything works fine.

File target membership, project build phases all look OK.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you added your `Resources` folder as a **folder reference**? Unless, all resources are added to the app bundle flatly regardless of the source folder structure. **Groups** are displayed in yellowish-brown (resources are added flatly), **Folder References** are displayed in blue (resources are added as in the same folder structure).

Comment: @OOPer yes, the folders have all been added properly and I can see them in the xcode config and project files. Everything works fine if I remove one of the files so I have no doubt they've been added correctly.

Comment: Just _added_ is not sufficient, are those folders displayed in blue?

Comment: @OOPer No, the folders are not showing up as blue in xcode...

Comment: Then you have not _added properly_. Remove the`Resources` folder (only reference, not move it to Trash) and add it again with Options `Added Folders:` set to `Create folder references`.

Comment: @OOPer that did it! Thanks, bud! If you wanna put it as an answer, I'll be glad to accept/vote it :)

Comment: Please take some time to post an answer yourself. I'd rather spend my time to find other issues which I can be some help.

Comment: @OOPer you sure you don't want to take credit/rep points?

Comment: I really like getting points, with my rules. I'll find other chances which fit better with my rules. If you find some answers of mine and you think them as useful, please up-vote them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting files must be added to XCode with the option 'Create folder references'